# convert id to unknown Class type and get its frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an object who i don't know is of what type, it could be `UILabel`, `UIImageView` or `UIButton`. i am checking for all three using `if` condition.

```
    if([obj2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [(UIImageView*)obj2 setFrame:frame];
    }
    else if ([obj2 isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        [(UILabel*)obj2 setFrame:frame];
    }
    else
    {
        [(UIButton*)obj2 setFrame:frame];
    }
```

My question is how i can get its frame again, `id` type don't have property `frame`. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: `UIView` instead of `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those classes share a common ancestor; `UIView`.  So blindly cast `id` to `UIView` and knock yourself out:

```
UIView *obj2View = (UIView *)obj2;
obj2View.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
CGRect r = obj2View.frame;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast them as a `UIView` by doing:

```
[(UIView *)obj2 frame]
```

Which you already seem to be doing, I don't see what your issue is?  Or if the 'id', is guaranteed to be a subclass of `UIView`, which by your example it seems it is, use `UIView` instead of `id` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It works without casting. Try this. It is working at my end. :

```
  id obj2 = some object;
  CGRect frame = someFrame;
  [obj2 setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Manual type casting is the best practice. Don't leave it to the compiler and get yourself spoiled.

Comment: If programmer knows that obj2 will belong to either UILabel,  UIImageView or UIButton objects, then whats wrong in it?